# Sync framework 2.1 and 2.0

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I have this type of architecture- Tablet application,Desktop Application,web application.. In tablet application its sync framework 2.1.Desktop 2.0 web 2.0 When syncing from Tab to Desktop i am upgrading metadata to 2.1, sync works fine between tab and desktop...Now when trying to sync between Desktop and Web it throws error as metadata of desktop app is upgraded. I cant upgrade web metadata as many desktop users are using 2.0 framework in their desktop. can anyone suggest me wat to do in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, you can't mix and match the metadata version. its either you upgrade everyone or you don't. (i think that's actually explicitly mentioned in the metadata upgrade docs.)

Comment: Thanks for answer,, I found some workaround...i renamed  some column  in Scope Config Table so its working fine...